# Hide instance (original) light while keeping the instanced versions

Tags: cycles-render-engine, modifiers, bezier-curves, light, instances

I've created a lightchain. For that lightchain I need a point light at every "bulb", as an emitting material is too weak of a lightsource. To achieve this I have created an array of planes that follows the curve of said lightchain.They are within the lightbulbs and they are hidden as shown in the instancing tab of the screenshot. Each plane instances a single point light.
**The problem** is, that the original point light can not be hidden in the render, without the instanced lights also being hidden. [image: how it is in the render]
The **only way I can get this to work** as I want it to, is in the viewport (render preview). By simply hiding the original light in the outliner. Trying to do this in the render disables not only it, but also every instanced light. Meaning either all of them, including the origin, or none of them are shown in the render.
I can not move the original light, as that changes the position of the instanced lights. How do I fix this? The only other way I came up with is to make the instances real just before rendering, and then hide the original lamp, but that is more of a workaround than a solution to the problem.
[image: how it should be, only works in the render preview]
[image]

Comment: Hello :). Just place the original light into a separate collection which you then disable (uncheck the box).

Comment: did you ever try to use emit material with strength 100 and set check to bloom? If this is not light enough i cannot help you....

Comment: Unclamping indirect light should make emissive materials better, I think

Comment: @Jachym Michal I tried putting it in a seperate collection, but that just disables all the lights.

Comment: @Chris As far as I know bloom isn't available in cycles, right? only through glare in the compositor.

Comment: @Allen Simpson I have yet to try setting it that high, but I'd like to use the point light method as that gives me more control over the brightness.

Comment: @Poppi: i did not see anything that you did this in cycles....so i assumed it was eevee ;)

Comment: @Poppi: well...i downloaded your blend file: it is eevee ...but you are asking for cycles? ah...well...ok ;) and yes, bloom is just in eevee

Comment: @Chris That was my bad, this is my first post and I thought I'd only export the lightchain so no one has to fight through the entire scene and it is clear what my problem is. I should have set it to cycles but I forgot, sorry.

Comment: Which Blender version do you use? In 2.92 it looks like the 2nd screenshot, the original light is not rendered (Cycles) but visible in the viewport

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution for this. Move the origin of the parent object where you instanced the light. This way the original light will move following the origin of the parent but the instanced light will stay in place.

[image: origin only toggle]